# What input shape should I take in first layer of Sequential model when the dimensions of the images are (2048*1536)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I am having an image dataset each image is of dimensions=(2048,1536).In ImageDataGenerator to fetch data from the directory, I have used the same target size i.e (2048,1536) but while making Sequential model first layer, what input shape should I have to use?? Will it be same as (2048,1536) or I can take any random shape like (224,224).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably flatten your input data by making a vector of size 3145728 (2048 * 1536). If your data is in a numpy array you can use `np.flatten()` ([numpy flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)).

Then your first layer can have the same shape as this vector.

Comment: Okk I will try this

Answer (score 1):

I would resize first the images with `cv2.resize()`. Do you really need all the information from such a big image?

For a sequential Model it follows for example:

`model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = (height,width, ndim)))
...`,

where `height` and `width` denote your input image dimensions and `ndim = 1` for greyscale and `ndim = 3` for colored images.

Comment: No i dont need all the information of image here, but what if in any case I want all the information of such a big image then should I have to give input shape same as of target size??

Comment: Well, If there are super little objects in the image necessary, then you might need a big image and a really deep model. However, I would try different resize shapes like `(200,150)` or `(100,75)` - error and trial. -- Please take a look at your model with `model.summary()`. The layers will show you how big the image is at every layer. And then think of the information important for you in the image: Is the information still retrievable from such a small image?

Comment: For these problem I am using keras pretrained model so how can I check it in that???

Answer (score 1):

The first(i.e. input)layer is supposed to be the number of features in your dataset. Regarding images, each pixel is considered as a feature. Hence in your case, the image dimension is (2048,1536) you need to flatten it out to get the total number of the pixel(i.e. features). If it is greyscaled image it would be (2048*1536*1) else if it is colour it would be(2048*1536*3).

Also, you use below code from TensorFlow/Keras API while Sequential model creation and it will take care of your input layer size

```
tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu) #1st hidden layer
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu) #2nd hidden layer
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation=tf.nn.softmax)])#output layer
```